# why soft limit in /proc/{pid}/limits is different with ulimit -Sn

Tags: linux, tomcat, shell, ulimit

I found hard limit value in /proc/{pid}/limits match the output of `ulimit -Hn` while soft limit value doesn't

my example output:

```
tomcat@myLinux:/home/azhang$ ulimit -Sn
1024
tomcat@myLinux:/home/azhang$ ulimit -Hn
1048576
tomcat@myLinux:/home/azhang$ ulimit -n
1024
```

So soft limit is **1024**

I have a tomcat running as tomcat user and i checked the limit of that process,

```
tomcat@myLinux:/home/azhang$ cat /proc/12257/limits 
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
....
Max processes             31854                31854                processes 
Max open files            1048576              1048576              files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
....
```

The soft limit of process 12257(tomcat) is **1048576**, same as hard limit and not **1024**

Is it a bug of /proc/{pid}/limits?

Comment: Did you run tomcat in the same session you exec `ulimit` command?

Comment: not for my above environment. I tried in another server: first I try `ulimit -Sn` and I get **1024**, try `ulimit -Hn` and get **4096**, then I confirmed ulimit was not set in startup tomcat script like /etc/init.d/tomcat_8080, catalina.sh, setenv.sh and I started tomcat by `/etc/init.d/tomcat_8080 start`, then I get soft&hard limit of tomcat process both as **4096**, different machine but same case.

Comment: It can be but. I can't get situation for such differences...

Comment: So I think it you are changing process limit not the user limits from configuration itself, can you please try to filter from config if you are doing so?

Comment: I have the same problem. On a debian system, after reboot, checking the user running nginx: `ulimit -Hn` shows **1048576**, but `cat /proc/<id>/limits` shows a hard file limit of **4096**. ‍♂️

Comment: According this [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/799592), the values in `/proc/{pid}/limits` are set by systemd, which require changing config in a systemd unit file.